# MySQL error 1305 - FUNCTION dbname.STUFF does not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I need to replace path for all children files in my files storage, e.g.:
When moving "Subfolder" to "NewFolder/Subfolder", I want all files even in "Subfolder/Folder/Subfolder" to replace only first part of path ("Subfolder/") with "NewFolder/Subfolder/". Not whole replace, because it affects not just first match of string. So I used this query:

```
$sql_stuff_length = strlen($just_path_old) + 1;
$db->setQuery(
    'UPDATE school_files_storage SET `path`=' . $db->quote($just_path_new) . ' WHERE `path`=' . $db->quote($just_path_old) . ';
     UPDATE school_files_storage SET `path`=STUFF(`path`, 1, ' . $sql_stuff_length . ', ' . $db->quote($just_path_new . '/') . ') WHERE `path` LIKE ' . $db->quote($just_path_old . '/%'
);
```

So final query is:

```
UPDATE school_files_storage SET `path`='NewFolder/Subfolder' WHERE `path`='Subfolder';
UPDATE school_files_storage SET `path`=STUFF(`path`, 1, 10, 'NewFolder/Subfolder') WHERE `path` LIKE 'Subfolder/%'
```

But it's giving me error:

#1305 - FUNCTION dbname.STUFF does not exist
MySQL version is 5.6

How to solve explained replacing of first occurence in path?

UPD: I tried TRIM,

```
                $db->setQuery(
                    'UPDATE school_files_storage SET `path`=' . $db->quote($just_path_new) . ' WHERE `path`=' . $db->quote($just_path_old) . ';
                     UPDATE school_files_storage SET `path`=CONCAT(' . $db->quote($just_path_new . '/') . ', TRIM(LEADING ' . $db->quote($just_path_old . '/') . ' FROM `path`)) WHERE `path` LIKE ' . $db->quote($just_path_old . '/%')
                );
```

But there are new error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE school_files_storage SET `path`=CONCAT('/', TRIM(LEADING '/' FROM `path`)' at line 2
```

Comment: Most query interfaces only support one SQL statement at a time, not multiple queries separated by commas. Run each UPDATE in its own call to setQuery().

Answer (score 1):

You can set one or more chars before the string to replace only the first.

```
UPDATE school_files_storage SET `path`= REPLACE(CONCAT('///',path), '///Subfolder','NewFolder/Subfolder') WHERE `path` LIKE 'Subfolder/%';
```